# How do I setup Hudson on a windows server so I can access it access it in any web browser?

Tags: hudson

### Question

I setup Hudson CI on a Windows 2008 server and now I want to be able to use the domain name to access it from any web browser.  Right now I can only access it by using http://localhost:8080.  How do I configure it to be public accessible? How do I open port 8080 in windows server 2008?

Comment: Have you opened port 8080 in your firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out your machine name! Right click on the 'My Computer' icon and go to the computer name tab. You can use the full name or just the part before the first '.' to replace `localhost`.

If you only want to reach the server from a LAN, the short name should be enough. Test that first on the server locally. If that works than try from another computer. If that doesn't work check all your firewalls and security settings.

Comment: How do open port 8080 in the windows firewall?

Comment: Try this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308127 -- if that does not help ask on ServerFault.com or superuser.com